# Creating and Saving New Photos Win32 Webcam Application

Tags: c++, winapi, stdstring, win32gui, lptstr

I am trying to make my webcam Win32 application save more than one photo at a time i.e. save one photo then another then another etc.

To do this, I am appending a string to an integer variable so that each new photo name can be unique and conform to the format of the second argument of CreateBMPFile. This would usually be a case of writing TEXT("string literal"), but I need to keep modifying the filename as each new photo is created.

```
PBITMAPINFO pbi = CreateBitmapInfoStruct(hwnd, hbm);
int i = 1;
std::string image = "..\\..\\..\\..\\WebCam\\frame" + std::to_string(i) + ".bmp";
while (!exists(image)) {
    LPTSTR filename = (LPTSTR)image.c_str();
    CreateBMPFile(hwnd, filename, pbi, hbm, hdcMem);
    i++;
}
```

This compiles and executes, however, when I click the "Grab Frame" button and it attempts to save it, the application crashes i.e. I cannot see the GUI anymore and it becomes a stagnant process.

I am using an exists() function to see whether the file exists in the system:

```
inline bool exists(const std::string& name) {
    struct stat buffer;
    return (stat(name.c_str(), &buffer) == 0);
}
```

I've also tried using sprintf_s() with the same result of crashing the application.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what "crashes the program" means, as that is a very vague problem description. What **specific** problem are you having? (If you don't understand the need for specificity, try calling your doctor and saying "I have a pain. What's causing it and how do I make it stop?" and see if you get an answer without providing more information.

Comment: @KenWhite I click the "Grab Frame" button and when it attempts to save it, the application crashes i.e. I cannot see the GUI anymore and it becomes a stagnant process. I am unsure of what has really happened.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that information there, where it can be seen, instead of burying it in a comment. The next step would be to use the debugger, and see where the problem is happening. Examining variables at that point should give you an indication of what's going on.

Comment: Note that you never rebuild your `image` string - simply incrementing `i` doesn't magically cause the string to update with the new number in it.